# Css scroll end not display

Tags: html, css

I use an old website template as my home automation system. 
Everything work well but I have a bug that I can't find.

http://88.182.191.233:8090/stack/

On a swiper slide, I load an ajax list of my music artists (I hard coded the list on the example). The list is loaded but the end is cropped.

On the example you can see that "Zayn" isn't display fully. If I add content before the list, even more artist aren't display.

So how can I display all artist on a div and keep headers fixed ? On responsive height ?

My other question is for the letter list, how can I append all letters to the entire height of the div ? On my mobile I only saw up to U letter.

Thank for your help !

PS : sorry for the code of my example site, I'm not a pro.

Comment: The site doesn't do anything on my machine. Links don't work, it doesn't scroll etc.

Comment: After a short delay, artists list must appear no need to use links as I remove some files.